# How can I use map() to triple each character of each string in a list, rather than tripling each string in the list?

Tags: python, mapping

I have the following `list`:

```
eight_bit_binary = ['01101000', '01100101', '01111001']
```

I would like to triple each item in `eight_bit_binary`, so for '01101000' -> "000111111000111000000000"; and same for the second and third item.

In my mind I know the following doesn't quite work, but it is close to what I am after:

```
eight_bit_binary = map(lambda n:n*3, eight_bit_binary)
```

It produces '01101000' -> "011010000110100001101000", which is not what I want of course.

How can I tweak it so that it does what I would like it to? I know there must be some for loop involved but I can't quite get it. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`map()` allows you to access and change each element of the list. You need to then access each member of those strings with another call to `map()`.

```py
binary = ['01101000', '01100101', '01111001']
longer = list(map(lambda n: ''.join(map(lambda x: x*3, n)), binary))
```

Also note I would probably use list comprehension here rather than a direct call to `map()`:

```py
[''.join(x*3 for x in b) for b in binary]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Quick question, when would it be more appropriate to use map then? Is it when we want to apply a method/function to each element in the list/string? Rather than a simple multiplication?

Comment: To be honest, I come from the world of Java and Javascript where `map()` and `filter()` are more natural. But I eventually found myself using list comprehension more often because 1) the result is a `list` rather than a `map` object, 2) the syntax seems a bit more simple and 3) there's less typing involved (`[...]` vs `list(map(lambda ...))`). There might be cases where the `map` function has slightly better performance but I think that's almost never relevant (premature optimization).

Answer (score 1):

```
eight_bit_binary = ['01101000', '01100101', '01111001']
eight_bit_binary = [''.join([c*3 for c in item]) for item in eight_bit_binary]
print(eight_bit_binary)
```

Result would be:

```
['000111111000111000000000', '000111111000000111000111', '000111111111111000000111']
```

Comment: The question asks how to use `map`. You don't use `map`.

Comment: oops, I just based on statement that the question author said "there must be some for loop involved but I can't quite get it. Any help would be great!". I should have noted that I suggest `comprehension` solution instead of using `map`

Comment: @not_speshal Showing the better way is a bonus :-)

Comment: @KellyBundy - I didn't say this isn't a good way. In fact, this is how I would do it. I just said it does not use `map` which OP seems to have wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Your `map(, eight_bit_binary)` applies the logic to each value of `eight_bit_binary`, you want that logic to be applied to the elements of each value, you need a second level of iteration

```
eight_bit_binary = ['01101000', '01100101', '01111001']
eight_bit_binary = ["".join(map(lambda n: n * 3, e)) for e in eight_bit_binary]
print(eight_bit_binary)
# ['000111111000111000000000', '000111111000000111000111', '000111111111111000000111']
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer azro. Quick question, when would it be more appropriate to use map then? Is it when we want to apply a more complex method/function to each element in the list/string? Rather than a simple multiplication?